# Xcode 7: UINavigationController's child view controller does not resize to fit parent's bounds

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode7

I have a UIViewController subclass that I am pushing on to a navigation controller stack within a larger UISplitViewController. However, when I build with Xcode 7, I am finding the that the UIViewController subclass is not resizing to fit the bounds of its parent navigation controller. This was not an issue when building with previous SDKs.

When I inspect the view of the child view controller, I am getting the standard 600x600 size.

The child view controller is entirely defined in code; I am not using IB for its layout or anything like that. What gives?

Comment: Hi Sean , any update on this , i am facing similar issue

Comment: nope. its a real downer.